# Which way is best for defining URL Redirect Web.config or in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, iis-8

I need to define URL redirect for my website so after search on google, I found two ways to do this. One way is to define the redirect rule in web.config file and the other is to create a rule in IIS. Now my question is, is there any difference between these two approaches? If yes then which approach is better?

If anyone knows please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. you already describied the differences - and what "is better" solely depends on your use case. if _you_ don't know which version is preferable, then it does not matter. anything more than that is purely opinion-based and therefore _explicitly_ off-topic. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between the two methods. If you create a rewrite rule in the IIS panel, it will also be displayed in the web.config. If you create a rewrite rule in web.config, you can also see it in the IIS panel. In other words, no matter which method you use to create rewrite rules, their effects are the same.